# Dark Souls P2DE: Trainer Laurientus

Tags: dark-souls

By chance, I told him where I learnt chaos magic ( chaos covenant ), but I didn't learn all spells from him, is there any possibility to learn it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of his spells should also be obtainable by the chaos convenant's trainer (The egg burdened outside the firekeeper) and from The advanced trainer after training your pyromancy flame is ready to be ascended (+15). The advanced trainer is found in blight town sitting next to a pillar directly straight from Quelaags Domain's entrance.